# Controls touched status affect each other when inside a form (Angular 5), why?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, input

I have a custom input component called "ui-textbox", when more than one instance of it exist inside a single form -in a regular page component-, **they all turn to touched if I touch any of them, and invalid if any of them is invalid, though they don't have the same names.** Note that when I inspect their parent form, I see that the form controls have correct validity and touch states, so it's only incorrect ng-classes are added on the input elements!

**TextBoxUI component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'ui-textbox',
  templateUrl: './textBox.ui.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textBox.ui.css']
})
export class TextBoxUI implements OnInit {


  private control: FormControl = new FormControl(this.value, Validators.compose([]));;
  private _group: FormGroup;
  private _name: string;
  private _value: string = '';


  @Input()
  get value(): string {
    return this._value;
  }
  @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter();
  set value(val) {
    if (this._value === val) return;

    this._value = val;
    this.valueChange.emit(val);

  }

  @Input()
  get name(): string {
    return this._name;
  }
  @Output() nameChange = new EventEmitter();
  set name(val) {
    if (this._name === val) return;
    this._name = val;
    this.nameChange.emit(val);
  }

  @Input()
  get group(): FormGroup {
    return this._group;
  }
  set group(val) {
    if (this._group === val) return;
    this._group = val;
    setTimeout(() => { this._group.addControl(this.name, this.control); }, 0);

  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {

    var arr = [];
    //.
    //.
    //some code
    arr.push(Validators.required);
    this.control.setValidators(arr);
    this.control.updateValueAndValidity();

  }

}
```

**TextBoxUI template:**

```
<input [formControl]="control"
       [formGroup]="group"
       type="text"
       [(ngModel)]="value">
```

**Page component:**

```
  import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
  import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

  @Component({
    selector: 'pageControls',
    templateUrl: './page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./page.component.css']
  })
  @HasibEvents()
  export class PageComponent implements OnInit {


    private mainForm: FormGroup;

    private textBoxName1: string = "textBox1";
    private textBoxValue1 = 3;

    private textBoxName2: string = "textBox2";
    private textBoxValue2 = 5;


    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
       this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
       });

    }

  }
```

**Page template:**

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm">
  <div class="row">
      <ui-textbox [(group)]="mainForm"
                  [(name)]="textBoxName1"
                  [(value)]="textBoxValue1"
                  ></ui-textbox>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
    <ui-textbox [(group)]="mainForm"
                [(name)]="textBoxName2"
                [(value)]="textBoxValue2"></ui-textbox>
  </div>
</form>
```

Why is this happening?

What am I missing?? I can't see what in code that would make Angular turn these two inputs touched or invalid together.
I searched a lot about this problem but found no results at all.

**Note:** this problem of incorrect ng-classes only happen when controls are surrounded with a form tag.

Comment: @yurzui, please post your comment as an answer so I accept it. Thank you

Comment: I posted the answer. Did it help?

Comment: sorry I forgot to check and mark it as accepted. Now accepted, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't place `formGroup` directive on the element where you have already add `formControl` directive. The behavior will be unexpectable.

So, remove `formGroup` property binding from `input control`

```
<input [formControl]="control" [formGroup]="group"
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```